# How to Navigate to Website from App in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, navigation

I want to navigate to playstore when user click on button
Like

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed:(){Navigtor.of(context)},child:Text("Navigate to website"),)
```

I don't want  to use any plugin like **webview_flutter**.

I don't Know how to achieve this. If you know the solution then answer this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [launch_review](https://pub.dev/packages/launch_review) library which used to open any url you want, and if you want to open in the app or in browser depends on the link you provides.
e.g to open Facebook in the app, use url like :

```
fb://page/115931433433385?referrer=app_link (Android)
```

or normal url to open in browser

```
https://www.facebook.com/trynketsapp
```

**webview_flutter** will open the link in your app as its browser, but this library will open it in another app.
Unless this is not what your're looking for

Answer (score 0):

use url_launcher package

void _launchURL() async =>
await canLaunch(_url) ? await launch(_url) : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
where the _url is your web link